# Windows Text to Speech uses which library and function

Tags: nasm

I am making a NASM code to invoke text to speech . I need to know which windows  library and function does windows "Text to speech" utility use( The default one ) . I tried searching on MSDN but its pointing me towards Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio , Microsoft Silverlight etc .

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Speech API or SAPI - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=vs.85).aspx

I am not very familiar with NASM so I cannot advice you on how to do it with NASM.

Comment: Thanks , It is indeed a Native API , now i need to figure out how to use it .

Comment: @Cherokee you're welcome, no problem :-) Sorry, I couldn't actually guide you properly in this one coz I don't know NASM

Comment: Thanks ,  will figure it out :) , For what is Coding without messing with the unknown :D and figuring it out .

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the below link. But not really sure, how you would implement it in an assembler program.

[Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=10121)